# flutter: how can I got the exact error response from API without DioError formating?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I want to display different messages to users based on the API error.

the problem is that Dio intercepts all `409` errors as a conflict and displays the same message every time.

```
I/flutter ( 4507):  12:06:44.286125 DEBUG    Global Loggy - DioError [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 409.
```

but API error response is:

```
{
    "title": "PALLET_NOT_CREATED",
    "status": 409,
    "detail": "Cannot create a new pallet, the preparer has already a pallet in status IN_PROGRESS",
    "timestamp": 1686218442060,
    "developerMessage": "SOME MESSAGE ERE",
    "code": "WMS_CLT_ERR_4",
    "errors": {}
}
```

is there's anyway i can use or handle errors without dioErrors ?

my DioService:

```
...
Future<Response<JSON>> post({
    required String endpoint,
    JSON? data,
    Options? options,
    CancelToken? cancelToken,
  }) async {
    final response = await _dio.post<JSON>(
      baseUrl + endpoint,
      data: data,
      options: options,
      cancelToken: cancelToken ?? _cancelToken,
    );
    return response;
  }
...
```

> NOTE: THIS IS ONLY THE POST REQUEST I HANDLED ALL OTHER METHODS`

service calling API

```
Future<PalletModel> createPallet(int batchId) async {
    try {
      final res = await _dioService.post(
        endpoint: CommonProperties.palletsByBatchId.replaceAll(
          ":batchId",
          batchId.toString(),
        ),
        data: {},
        options: Options(
          extra: {
            'requiresAuthToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
      return PalletModel.fromJson(res.data!);
    } catch (e) {
      logDebug('error is:');
      logDebug(e);
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply `try/cath` to your api `post` call

```
Future<Response<JSON>> post({
    required String endpoint,
    JSON? data,
    Options? options,
    CancelToken? cancelToken,
  }) async {
     try {
        final response = await _dio.post<JSON>(
          baseUrl + endpoint,
          data: data,
          options: options,
          cancelToken: cancelToken ?? _cancelToken,
        return response;
    );
    }
    on DioError catch(e) {
         print(e.response!.data.toString)
   }

    
   
  }
```

After catching a DioError, you can manipulate data, checking response body, etc